# In 那个是我工作上的东西, what is the difference between 工作上 and 工作?

Tags: meaning, usage

> 那个是我工作上的东西

Why is there a 上 in this sentence? How does it change the meaning? Ie, what's the difference between 工作的东西 and 工作上的东西? When should 工作上 be used as opposed to 工作?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`上` here means `about（相关）`.

Try to understand it like this: `那个是我工作相关的东西`

If you omit `上`, it'd be understand as the item `used` for work rather than `about`.

`那个是我工作的东西` sounds a bit like `那个是我工作用的东西`.

Anyway, both are rarely spoken for native Mandarin speakers. You'd better provide more context.

Comment: That sounds right. Someone I know accidentally sent me an email and I asked what it was about.

Comment: I agree, not used so often, since someone who knows you typically knows what you do and you don't need to explain your work to them.

Comment: Sometimes this happens. For example, you are a professional engineer at NASA, your family would surely ask you a lot when they see your equipments. In this case you may answer `那个是我工作用的东西` or `那个是我上班用的东西` rather than `那个是我工作上的东西`

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by 'both are rarely spoken'? Why would they be rarely spoken?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's not so much difference. `工作上的东西,工作的东西`both mean something related to your work.

And `上`actually doesn't mean too much , Chinese language is not that strict as English, you don't have to understand every word.

More examples about `上`

> -孩子,你在看什么?(Son, what' are you viewing?)
>   -妈妈,我在看学习上的书(Mom, I am just viewing some academical books)

Comment: Chinese language is not that strict as English - I agree. But I don't think Chinese people will ever say something like `我在看学习上的书`. That is too weird.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Well, sometimes I said it. Yes, we often said `学习方面的书`.

Comment: I'm just curious are you native? (please don't take it personally) I think in this particular case, a child would be more likely to say `妈妈，我在看书` or `妈妈，我在学习`. Personally when using `上`, I often use it with `事情` following, for example: `这些都是工作上的事情`.